# Tensorflow operation to combine Iterator string handles within a single session feed_dict

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to generate minibatches with varying combinations of multiple datasets in a manner that uses the data api and does not cause *tensor leakage* (i.e., increasing the number of graph ops over time). For example, minibatch 1 might be `a1, a2, b1, b2` followed by minibatch 2 with `a3, a4, c1, c2`.

Is it possible to run a single session on multiple initialized dataset iterators via the "string handle feed_dict method" (see **feedable** at [TF](http://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) ). Is there an op to combine two Iterator.string_handle objects? I have a minimal working example below that shows my issue at the end after the sys.exit.

```
import tensorflow as tf  # v.1.4
import sys

# Predetermine minibatch size.
num_per_class = 6

# Create example datasets.
ds0 = tf.data.Dataset.range(0, 100, 2)
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.range(1, 101, 2)

# Minibatchify. Note: could use adjustable tensor for minibatch size.
ds0 = ds0.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(num_per_class))
ds1 = ds1.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(num_per_class))

# Run forever.
ds0 = ds0.repeat()
ds1 = ds1.repeat()

# Dataset iterators.
ds0_itr = ds0.make_initializable_iterator()
ds1_itr = ds1.make_initializable_iterator()

# Switcher handle placeholder, iterator and ultimate minibatch datums.
switcher_h = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
switcher_h_itr = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(switcher_h,
                                                     ds0.output_types,
                                                     ds0.output_shapes)
mb_datums = switcher_h_itr.get_next()

# Start session.
sess = tf.Session()

# Dataset iterator handles.
ds0_h = sess.run(ds0_itr.string_handle())
ds1_h = sess.run(ds1_itr.string_handle())

# *Separate* dataset feed_dicts.
ds0_fd = {switcher_h: ds0_h}
ds1_fd = {switcher_h: ds1_h}

# Initialize dataset iterators.
sess.run([ds0_itr.initializer, ds1_itr.initializer])

# Print some datums from either (XOR) dataset.
print('ds0 data:  {}'.format(sess.run(mb_datums, ds0_fd)))
print('ds1 data:  {}'.format(sess.run(mb_datums, ds1_fd)))

# DESIRE A MINIBATCH OF SIZE 12:  6 FROM EACH.
sys.exit()
ds01_fd = {switcher_h: OP_TO_COMBINE_STRING_HANDLES(ds0_h, ds1_h)}
print('ds0+ds1:  {}'.format(sess.run(mb_datums, ds01_fd)))
```

Comment: I understand you want to create batches by combining elements from several `Dataset` objects. Could you be a bit more specific about how you want these varying combinations to be generated? Would something like [`interleave`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave) work for you?

Comment: I would like to combine datasets adaptively (not predetermined). I am hoping to avoid any costly reinitialization of my (shuffled/prefetched/cached) pipelines. I don't want to define new ops after execution begins (tensor leak).

Comment: Note that the mb_datums tensor feeds my training ops, so I can't have a separate switcher_h for each dataset.

Comment: Regarding **interleave**.  Interleaving very large datasets takes a very long time. I suppose I could collect the minibatch datums from the separate datasets, and then interleave these, but this would create several additional ops each time the ratios of the datasets were changed.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but for others who get to this question as I did and don't want to figure it out themselves: here's a minimal example that uses one dataset to dynamically select or "get_next()" from one of two other datasets:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.full(100, 1)
y = np.full(100, 2)

x_i = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x).make_one_shot_iterator()
y_i = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y).make_one_shot_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sesh:
  [x_h, y_h] = sesh.run([x_i.string_handle(), y_i.string_handle()])

  z_d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.random.sample(100))
  z_d = z_d.map(lambda x: tf.gather([x_h, y_h], tf.cast(tf.round(x), tf.int32)))
  z_i = z_d.make_one_shot_iterator()

  picker_i = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(z_i.get_next(), tf.int64).get_next()

  for i in range(100):
    print(sesh.run([picker_i]))
```